# Automatically open a downloaded file Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that goes to a website and logs in. Then, it presses an "Export to Excel" button and gets the save as dialog box. Is there any way that I can press "Open" and get the file open? If you need any HTML code from the website, let me know, because this information is confidential. Thanks in advance!!

```
Sub Download()
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://broomfield.flatironslibrary.org/"

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

 IE.document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs header-button header-primary")(0).Click
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
IE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "user"
IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "pass"
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary extraModalButton") (0).Click
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
IE.navigate ("http://broomfield.flatironslibrary.org/MyAccount/CheckedOut?exportToExcel")

   'This is where the dialog box appears
 End sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `sendkeys %o` ([alt]+o)?

Comment: It worked! I've been looking for a shortcut like this for a LOONG time. Thanks you.